# Jquery Redactor: Replace marked text to initialize a new editor instance

Tags: jquery, redactor

I'm trying to solve this simple problem, but I don't get it.
I'm using the Redactor editor with its API (http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/)

```
<div id="redactor">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
    <p>Anything else</p>
</div>
```

The user should be able to select i.e. the word "ipsum", press a button and put the selected block into a new editor instance at the same position:

```
var html = $('#redactor').redactor('getBlock');
```

I need to change the selected block to this:

```
<div id="redactor">
    <div id="redactor_new" class="box"></div>
    <p>Anything else</p>
</div>
```

After this I will initialize a new redactor instance:

```
$('#redactor_new').redactor(); // Initialize the new redactor instance
```

and put the content into this new redactor:

```
$("#redactor_new").redactor('insertHtmlAdvanced', html);
```

How do I do that replacement? I don't find the correct function in the API...
The user should also be able to delete such a created instance (destroy) - the same thing as above, but the other way round......

And is it possible to prevent the usage of an ID (i.e. #redactor_new) for the new div-container, as it should be used dynamically?

**JS Fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/u59qX/2/**

Comment: but how do i remove exactly the selected block with .remove() as the var html consists only a string (i guess)?

Comment: your wordings in the question is not clear..can you be little more precise what you need and add the example html

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it gets more clear...

Comment: just saw now..it looks a clear now..let me understand

Comment: `$('#redactor_new').redactor();` why are you doing this. any call should be on `redactor` this

Comment: you are having editor on which div ?

Comment: The main editor is on #redactor. I want to get a second editor on #redactor_new. Therefore I have to add this new div-container. So I will have at last two editors (nested). But the script should be in the way, that I can create multiple new instances...

Comment: you want all this to happen on load ?

Comment: No. I want to create a own Button. So the user can select a text -> click button -> selected block will be transfered to a new instance. In the same way the user should be able to do it the other way round, that means: destroy a created editor but leave the content at the same place. P.S.: Thanks for the fiddle...

Comment: you need to mention about the button in the question..When some editor is not that famous then giving more details about what you are trying to do will help you solve it sooner

Comment: can you update the fiddle. with the complete code what you have tried and update the link here. add the button code

Comment: I'm sorry! I updated my question one more time. I really hope it is now clear.

Comment: This is what I have, but it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/u59qX/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u59qX/3/ try this I added a button at the begginneing not plugin..button icon is not visible as i didnt set it. just look at the functionality

Comment: Thanks! That is a great help for me! There is a little problem for me: "$('.redactor_new').redactor();" will affect all elements with this class. But it should only initiate the editor, which has been inserted right now. You know what I mean?